# How to Bulk delete the document from solr without actually deleting the node?

Tags: 7, nodes, search

The scenario is to delete bulk documents from apache solr, without deleting the actual node from the database. I am aware that when the node is un-published it will be deleted from solr.

But as my node are very large containing 1000's of terms I don not want to use node-save to un-publish the node.

Is there any hook or function which un-publishes the node and deletes from solr by minimal load (definitely not node save)  ?

UPDATE:

- Drupal Version : 7.15
- Modules: Apachesolr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer on exploring the apache solr module,

**STEP 1**

Select the nodes from the node table alone or by joining the apachesolr index entities table,

```
// Check for unpublished content that wasn't deleted from the index.
  $table = apachesolr_get_indexer_table('node');

 // Select the nids from the node table 
  $query = db_select($table, 'aien')
    ->fields('aien', array('entity_id'))
    ->condition('n.nid', 0);
  $query->leftJoin('node', 'n', 'n.nid = aien.entity_id');
  $nodes = $query->execute()->fetchAllAssoc('nid');
```

**STEP 2**

Chunk it to some limit and call the apachesolr_index_nodeapi_mass_delete function

```
      $node_lists = array_chunk($nodes, '100', TRUE);
  foreach ($node_lists as $nodes) {
    watchdog('Apache Solr', 'On cron running apachesolr_nodeapi_mass_delete() on nids @nids', array('@nids' => implode(',', array_keys($nodes))), WATCHDOG_WARNING);
    if (!apachesolr_index_nodeapi_mass_delete($nodes, $table)) {
      // Solr query failed - so stop trying.
      break;
    }
  }
```